# How to run python script installed in virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-venv, python-poetry

So in a machine I have a specific python package installed. This python package include a script defined with `[tool.poetry.scripts]` in the `pyproject.toml` file.

When I develop updates I create a virtual environment using venv: `python3.8 -m venv env`, source it with `source ./env/bin/activate` and then install the update with `python3.8 -m pip install -e .`

However when then I call the script of the package it does not use the package installed inside the virtual environment (even thought I sourced it) but the script of the same package already installed (without the currently developped update) outside of the virtual environment. Any idea how I can prevent this behavior?

Sincerely